# Strange observation on nodejs infinite loop function execution

Tags: node.js, async-await, infinite-loop

I recently came across the article [Tail call optimization in ECMAScript 6](http://2ality.com/2015/06/tail-call-optimization.html). I was interested in testing the TCO behavior (Even though I later found that the TCO was not supported by nodejs 8+ as mentioned by the article) and found behavior that I could not understand.

1. **Plain loop function**

   ```
   'use strict';

   process.on('SIGTERM', () =>
   {
       console.log('SIGTERM received');
       process.exit(0);
   })

   process.on('SIGINT', () =>
   {
       console.log('SIGINT received');
       process.exit(0);
   })

   process.on('uncaughtException', (error) =>
   {
       console.error('Uncaught exception', error);
       process.exit(1);
   })

   process.on('unhandledRejection', (error) =>
   {
       console.error('Unhandled rejection', error);
       process.exit(0);
   })

   let counter = 0;

   function test()
   {
       console.log(`Counter: ${counter++}`);
       test();
   }

   console.log('Test started');

   test();

   console.log('Test ended');
   ```

   This version of code produces:

   ```
   Test started
   Counter: 0
   ...
   Counter: 10452
   Uncaught exception RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
       at WriteStream.removeListener (events.js:306:28)
       at write (console.js:130:12)
       at Console.log (console.js:135:3)
       at test (/test.js:31:13)
       at test (/test.js:32:5)
       at test (/test.js:32:5)
       at test (/test.js:32:5)
       at test (/test.js:32:5)
       at test (/test.js:32:5)
       at test (/test.js:32:5)
       at test (/test.js:32:5)
       at test (/test.js:32:5)
       at test (/test.js:32:5)
       at test (/test.js:32:5)
       at test (/test.js:32:5)
       at test (/test.js:32:5)
   ```
2. **Async loop function without any await within the function**

   ```
   'use strict';

   process.on('SIGTERM', () =>
   {
       console.log('SIGTERM received');
       process.exit(0);
   })

   process.on('SIGINT', () =>
   {
       console.log('SIGINT received');
       process.exit(0);
   })

   process.on('uncaughtException', (error) =>
   {
       console.error('Uncaught exception', error);
       process.exit(1);
   })

   process.on('unhandledRejection', (error) =>
   {
       console.error('Unhandled rejection', error);
       process.exit(0);
   })

   let counter = 0;

   async function test()
   {
       console.log(`Counter: ${counter++}`);
       test();
   }

   console.log('Test started');

   test();

   console.log('Test ended');
   ```

   This version of code produces:

   ```
   Test started
   Counter: 0
   ...
   Counter: 6967
   Test ended
   ```
3. **Async loop function with await within the function**

   ```
   'use strict';

   const bluebird = require('bluebird');

   process.on('SIGTERM', () =>
   {
       console.log('SIGTERM received');
       process.exit(0);
   })

   process.on('SIGINT', () =>
   {
       console.log('SIGINT received');
       process.exit(0);
   })

   process.on('uncaughtException', (error) =>
   {
       console.error('Uncaught exception', error);
       process.exit(1);
   })

   process.on('unhandledRejection', (error) =>
   {
       console.error('Unhandled rejection', error);
       process.exit(0);
   })

   let counter = 0;

   async function test()
   {
       await bluebird.delay(1);
       console.log(`Counter: ${counter++}`);
       test();
   }

   console.log('Test started');

   test();

   console.log('Test ended');
   ```

   This version of code runs non-stop.

**In Summary:**

1. plain loop function: stops at counter 10452 and throws RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
2. Async loop function without any await within the function: stops at counter 6967 without any error
3. Async loop function with await within the function: runs non-stop

Can anyone explain this behavior differences or point me to any keyword i can google?

Comment: My guess would be that the first function does not benefit from last-call-optimization, hence the stack overflows when calling test().
The second version with async ends while the test calls are being done (async). That's why the counter stops at 6k without error. The third option is either too slow or it actually benefits from the last-call-optimization scheme (where infinite recursion is possible)

Comment: Hi @MartínZaragoza according to https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-proper_tail_calls_(tail_call_optimisation) (which is mentioned in that article), the TCO is not supported by nodejs.

Comment: Sure but if the third option actually runs "non-stop" (literally , not for a "very long time") then TCO is happenning (or at least some nodejs recursive optimization scheme), else you cannot have infinite recursive function calls.

Comment: @MartínZaragoza if TCO is happening, then it should also make version 1/2 do infinite recursion but it does not. Very confused.

Comment: I'm confused as well. Perhaps there's a different memory management scheme when using async and await...

Comment: This is one f*** interesting question btw