# Will async recursive function without parameters leak memory or get stack overflow?

Tags: javascript

I have a asynchronous task that takes a lot of time and it needs to be executed repeatedly.

The easy solution is:

```
const timeoutPromise = delay => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));

async function infiniteRecursiveLoop() {
  await longLastingWork();
  await timeoutPromise(10000);  // each time work is done, wait 10s and then run it again
  infiniteRecursiveLoop();
}
```

**Since I don't use any parameters and I don't `await` the result of the recursive call, this should not leak any memory nor get stack overflow, right? Because I'm not sure at all.**

I need this for recent Firefox and Chrome.

**EDIT:**
Actually I can just use `while(true) {...}`, there is no need for recursion :). But still I would like to know.

**EDIT 2:**
After testing more intensive version:

```
(async function infiniteRecursiveLoop() {
  await Promise.resolve();
  infiniteRecursiveLoop();
})();
```

**It seems that this is specific to environment:**

- NodeJS 12 - ok
- Chrome 77 - ok
- Firefox 70 - memory leak, no stack overflow

But why...?

Comment: whats wrong with [`setInterval`?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: @Liam `setInterval` won't wait for execution of the long lasting task. In my case, the task often takes longer than the interval.

Comment: Use `setTimeout` then. I don't see anything particularly "dangerous" here.

Comment: You don't see anything wrong with infinite recursion in a program? Even simply as bad practice?

Comment: You seem to be giving async await particular leak causing powers here. It's just a simplicifcation of promises which is a simplification of call backs. The JS engines garbage collector should clean up quite well and providing your not creating huge quanities of memory I don't really see why this would cause an issue anymore than running this non async. It's generally not very clear what your asking TBH

Comment: Why is it "bad practice" (whatever that means) @Michael?

Comment: What does async await have to do with anything? Recursion is recursion. It causes a memory leak in firefox, which suggests that chrome and node have to do something special to handle this unpleasant scenario. This is not a memory issue, but a call stack issue. An infinite call stack.

Comment: @icl7126 I would recommend you recreate this question in terms of your edit2, as that is a very interesting outcome, and some brighter minds could shed some light as to why it works in chrome and node. The most important point for your purposes here is that recursion is inappropriate for your use case, makes the code more complicated, and in some cases can cause memory leaks. There are no advantages to using recursion for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is infinitely recursive, so yes, it will cause an error.

Since you want to wait ten seconds for the next call to go out, make the next call to infiniteRecursiveLoop in your setTimeout function instead.

```
async function infiniteRecursiveLoop() {
  await longLastingWork();
  setTimeout(infiniteRecursiveLoop, 10000);
}
```

This might shed some light on the issue:

[Strange observation on nodejs infinite loop function execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51844939/strange-observation-on-nodejs-infinite-loop-function-execution)

While it may be possible to do this in *some* cases, it is most assuredly bad practice to use unnecessary infinite recursion.

Comment: Yes, this looks much less dangerous, HOWEVER I'm not sure my code will fail either. I've just tried to execute it in NodeJS and it seems like pretty nice infinite loop without memory leak: `(async function infiniteRecursiveLoop() {
  await Promise.resolve();
  infiniteRecursiveLoop();
})();`

Comment: It might _seem_ nice, but that's because this is working very very slowly. Eventually it will cause a stack overflow _because that's how infinite recursion works_. Furthermore, you don't actually need recursion in this example. What you want is a loop that continuously calls a function. Recursion is entirely inappropriate for this use case.

Comment: What make you think this will cause "an error"? What error exactly?